# Почему у меня так медленно работает переключение между вкладками в MS Excel?

Tags: excel

Excel файл весит относительно мало (мегабайт) содержит 2 вкладки общей численностью 1500 строчек, при переходе на с  первой на вторую вкладку Excel начинает тормозить ужасно (программа не отвечает), в чем проблема и как это исправить?

OFFICE 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На листе '2018' ничего криминального не обнаружено, зато на '2019' - 59295 объектов!

Откуда они там взялись - можно только догадываться. Обычно размножение популяции жителей происходит при копировании. Где-то как-то завелся объект нулевой высоты или ширины (например, удалили столбец или задали ему нулевую ширину, а в столбце жили кнопка или график). Позже копировали диапазон - у объекта появился братик или сестричка. Потом еще раз. Потом еще...

---

Увидеть население - `Ctrl+G`-*Выделить-Объекты-ОК*. Но операция длительная и придется подождать. Если надоело ждать - `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`, візвать диспетчер задач и завершить задачу для *Excel*

**Удаляем тормоза. Вариант1**. Больше для информации, т.к. удаление объектов будет происходить долго.

Заходим в редактор *VBA* - `Alt+F11`

`Ctrl+R` - если нет окна проектов (*Project-VBAProject*), оно появится.

`Ctrl+G` - отобразить окно  *Immediate*.

Вставляем новый модуль в дерево любого проекта - `Insert-Module`

Открываем модуль и пишем в него нехитрый макрос:

```
Sub DelObj()
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Count
    ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Delete
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects.Count, 64, ""
End Sub
```

Код чистит активный лист.

Первая строка считает количество объектов на листе и выводит результат в окно *Immediate*. Вторая - удаление объектов. Третья просигналит, что мучения закончены - покажет сообщение с нулем (объекты удалены).

Если есть желание повторить, перед закрытием книги не сохранять изменения :)

---

**Удаляем тормоза. Вариант2**. Более быстрый.

Файлы с расширением `.xlsx` по сути своей - архивы, содержащие целый набор папок и файлов. Вот это и поможет удалить объекты быстро.

Книга закрыта. Правый клик на файле - *Открыть с помощью - Архиватор*.

В раскрывшемся архиве открыть папку `xl`. Здесь еще одна папка - `drawings`, а в ней - файл с информацией об объектах (`drawing1.xml`).

Удалить папку `drawings` (но - внимание! Будут удалены ВСЕ объекты со всех листов). Закрыть архив.

В итоге имеем файл объемом окло 250 кБ и без скрытых проблем.

Comment: Спасибо,вроде помогло)) тоже как-то раз нагугливал примерно то же самое , - почистил - месяц позаполняли этот же файлик - и снова здравствуйте... -

Comment: После чисти проблем не должно быть. Но вполне вероятно, что подтягиваете объекты при копировании из других источников